# How to enable browser's password manager for use in web extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a web extension that requires the user to login to a service. Everything works as expected, but the the browser's password manager never prompts for or remembers the user's credentials. When I run the my application outside of the extension the browser has no problem recognizing the login fields and allows me to fill them with credentials.

I've tried setting the `privacy` permission in `manifest.json`, but that doesn't seem to grant the required access. The only thing that I can think of is that we are currently running the extension in development mode as an unsigned extension. I can't find any documentation that says this might be the cause, so I'm hoping that someone can either confirm that is the case, provide information about what I'm missing, or at very least confirm that you can utilize the browser's configured password manager to supply credentials to a form within an extension?

Comment: Browsers don't implement this functionality for extensions, apparently.

Comment: Any chance you can back that statement up with a link to some documentation @wOxxOm? I'd really like to confirm that this is actually the case rather than speculate about it.

Comment: Look in the source code. For example, Chrome [apparently](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/password_manager/chrome_password_manager_client.cc;l=1194;drc=800532c0bf6712ea4ab5928da9e776d6607a10b1) excludes extensions explicitly.